# __pthread_kill on second request

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am getting json array response from particular url
On first request every thing is working fine but when second request goes then application crashes.

> libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
>   0x1082f885c:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax
>   0x1082f8861:  movq   %rcx, %r10
>   0x1082f8864:  syscall 
>   0x1082f8866:  jae    0x1082f8870               ; __pthread_kill + 20
>   0x1082f8868:  movq   %rax, %rdi
>   0x1082f886b:  jmp    0x1082f5175               ; cerror_nocancel
>   0x1082f8870:  retq
>   0x1082f8871:  nop
>   0x1082f8872:  nop
>   0x1082f8873:  nop

**StackTrace**

> 2015-07-16 13:44:37.126 Contact Book[15714:106637] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318/UITableView.m:1582
>   2015-07-16 13:44:37.341 Contact Book[15714:106637] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (11), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105cd53f5 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107803bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105cd525a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
>       3   Foundation                          0x000000010616c28f -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
>       4   UIKit                               0x000000010663346a -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 11746
>       5   Contact Book                        0x0000000105ae6a11 _TFFC12Contact_Book20MasterViewController38updateSearchResultsForSearchControllerFS0_FCSo18UISearchControllerT_U_FTGSQCSo6NSData_GSQCSo13NSURLResponse_GSQCSo7NSError__T_ + 2625
>       6   Contact Book                        0x0000000105ae6bb3 _TTRXFo_oGSQCSo6NSData_oGSQCSo13NSURLResponse_oGSQCSo7NSError__dT__XFo_iTGSQS__GSQS0__GSQS1____iT** + 51
>       7   Contact Book                        0x0000000105ae4091 _TPA__TTRXFo_oGSQCSo6NSData_oGSQCSo13NSURLResponse_oGSQCSo7NSError__dT__XFo_iTGSQS__GSQS0__GSQS1____iT__ + 81
>       8   Contact Book                        0x0000000105ae6e83 _TTRXFo_iTGSQCSo6NSData_GSQCSo13NSURLResponse_GSQCSo7NSError___iT__XFo_oGSQS__oGSQS0__oGSQS1___dT__ + 35
>       9   Contact Book                        0x0000000105ae6f0f _TTRXFo_oGSQCSo6NSData_oGSQCSo13NSURLResponse_oGSQCSo7NSError__dT__XFdCb_dGSQS__dGSQS0__dGSQS1___dT__ + 127
>       10  CFNetwork                           0x0000000108aaebbb **49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 157
>       11  Foundation                          0x000000010618fccf __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 7
>       12  Foundation                          0x00000001060cfb32 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 98
>       13  Foundation                          0x00000001060b2104 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 645
>       14  Foundation                          0x00000001060b1d13 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
>       15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107fa87f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107f90bf4 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1417
>       17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107f90506 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 235
>       18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107f92ff7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 682
>       19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107f9463c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 52
>       20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010833eef8 _pthread_wqthread + 314
>       21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000108341fb9 start_wqthread + 13
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)

I have following code

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController,     UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate  {

var completeData = NSMutableArray()
var nameData = NSMutableArray()


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}


var searchController : UISearchController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)

    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.delegate = self
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar

    self.definesPresentationContext = true
}
    var flag = false
    var task: NSURLSessionTask!

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    var inputText = searchController.searchBar.text as NSString

    if inputText.length > 3 {
        //TODO repalce space by %20

        if flag{
            task.cancel()}

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://172.26.1.39:8080/ContactBook/search?term="+inputText);

        task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url){(data, response, error) in

            if(error != nil){
                println("SOME ERROR")
                return
            }

            var parseError: NSError?

            var jsonArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &parseError) as NSArray

            if parseError != nil {
                println("something wrong")
                return
            }


            self.completeData.removeAllObjects()
            self.nameData.removeAllObjects()

            var tempObject : NSDictionary;

            for var i=0; i < jsonArray.count; i++ {
                var jsonDict = jsonArray[i] as NSDictionary
                self.completeData.insertObject(jsonDict, atIndex: 0)
                var name = jsonDict.valueForKey("name")! as NSString
                self.nameData.insertObject(name, atIndex: 0)
                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
                self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }
        }
        flag = true
        task.resume()
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Segues

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let object = completeData[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary
            (segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController).detailItem = object
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Table View

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return nameData.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let object = nameData[indexPath.row] as NSString
    cell.textLabel?.text = object.description
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return false
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty clear error message, just read it. Quote:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (11), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted,
>   0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

It says:

- after the update (insert/delete) you've got 1 cell in section 0,
- but before you did update the table view, you had 11 cells there, then you did insert 1 cell, thus it expects 11+1 cells, not 1

Problem is that number of cells in section `0` equals to `nameData.count`. And your code (removed unrelated parts) ...

```
self.nameData.removeAllObjects()   <----- (delete)

var tempObject : NSDictionary;

for var i=0; i < jsonArray.count; i++ {
  var jsonDict = jsonArray[i] as NSDictionary
  var name = jsonDict.valueForKey("name")! as NSString
  self.nameData.insertObject(name, atIndex: 0) <----- (insert)
  let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
  self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath],
    withRowAnimation: .Fade)  <------ (insert)
}
```

... removes all objects from `self.nameData`, but not from table view.

Table view cells and your backing store is not synced.

**Reload Data**

Remove `self.tableView.insert...` line and place `self.tableView.reloadData()` just after the for loop. It reloads the whole table view.

```
self.nameData.removeAllObjects()

var tempObject : NSDictionary;

for var i=0; i < jsonArray.count; i++ {
  var jsonDict = jsonArray[i] as NSDictionary
  var name = jsonDict.valueForKey("name")! as NSString
  self.nameData.insertObject(name, atIndex: 0)
  let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Or reload just one section.

```
func reloadSections(_ sections: NSIndexSet)
```

**Delete Items & Then Insert**

If you do not want to reload all cells (whole table view), you must keep in mind that your backing store for data must be kept in sync with table view. In other words - if you do remove cell from table view, you must remove it from your backing store. If you do insert cell into table view, you must insert it into backing store. And vice versa.

In your case, you call `self.nameData.removeAllObjects()`, but you **didn't** delete table view cells for these objects. You should call ...

```
func deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [NSIndexPath])
```

... on `self.tableView` for all objects you did remove from `self.nameData`.

If you do lot of `deleteItems.../insertItems/...` calls, it's good to wrap them in `performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)`:

```
func performBatchUpdates(_ updates: (() -> Void)?,
  completion completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
```

> Animates multiple insert, delete, reload, and move operations as a group.