# How can I reload a UITableView in a VC as soon as the presented modal vc is dismissed?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am working in **Swift 2** and have a **Master-Detail-Template**. The Detail view controller contains a table view, in which elements can be added over a modal view, presented by the Detail view controller (using **Core Data**). I tried to use a delegate which I integrated into the Detail view controller, which tells it to reload the table view's data when the modal view is dismissed, but it doesn't reload the data until I select another element in the Master View of the **Master-Detail-Template**. This is the delegate in the `newSittingVC`:

```
protocol newSittingVCDelegate {
    func saveReload()
}
```

When the user wants to dismiss the modal view, this code is called:

```
self.delegate!.saveReload()
presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

which calls this in the Detail View VC:

```
func saveReload() {
    sittingTable.reloadData()
    //self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

It doesn't work that way I described. Does anybody know a way that will work. Even forcing the view to redraw with setNeedsDisplay() didn't work.

EDIT:
[image: This is what Xcode looks like when I set the breakpoint. Any tips how to precede with the information?]

Comment: Are you sure that `self.delegate` is not `nil?`

Comment: Yes. in the prepareForSegue method I set the destination's delegate to "self" (which is the Detail VC). The delegate works just fine, I can print() to the console and everything with the included delegate method and it works fine. But anything that has to do with altering something in the UI will fail.

Comment: Did you try to debug it whether the `reloadData()` get called?

Comment: I tried including a print("text") both before and after the reloadData(). Both get called and printed. The table is not reloaded

Comment: Set a break point to see whether that `reloadData()` getting called. It's a really critical skills for software development.

Comment: I just added the breakpoint. But as I am still a beginner, unfortunately I do not know how to process the information. I'll add a screenshot of what Xcode looks like at the moment

Comment: @LucasHuang if `self.delegate` is `nil` / not set, `self.delegate!` will crash and there's no problem with crash.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It will crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31452747/581190) where I describe that you have to sync your backing store along with `UITableView`. You've got pretty similar problem.

In your callback, you're just calling `sittingTable.reloadData()`. What it does? It calls all these `UITableViewDataSource` delegate methods like `numberOfSections...`, ... along with `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`. And these methods do what? They return values based on your `sitzungen` array (`count`, ...). And you probably know where the problem is now - did you update `sitzungen` array? No, you didn't.

So, in your `saveReload()` method you have to execute fetch request again (in the same way as you do in `setupSittingTable`) and when your `sitzungen` array is updated, then (no sooner) call `sittingTable.reloadData()`. This should fix your problem.

---

Another points ...

Don't call your delegate methods in this way ...

```
self.delegate!.saveReload()
```

... change it to ...

```
self.delegate?.saveReload()
```

... what's the difference? I assume your delegate is optional (`?`) and when the delegate will not be set (`nil`), it will crash. Because `!` is force unwrapping optional and if it's `nil`, it just crashes. If you replace `!` with `?` it does this:

- if `self.delegate != nil` - `saveReload()` is called,
- if `self.delegate == nil` - nothing happens and no crash as well.

You can learn more in Optional Chaining chapter, especially in the [Calling Methods Through Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID249).

Don't use `sittingCell` as a class name. Class name, types, ... should start with upper case letter (camel case). So the correct class name is `SittingCell`. First lower case letter is used for function name, property name, ...

Also please, next time, don't use images, it's better to copy & paste & properly format code in your question as a text. It's hard to read it, ...

Comment: Also if you do want to learn more, check [NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/), which handles these updates automatically. [Here](http://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/03/05/displaying-data-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift/) is an article about usage of it in Swift. But it's another level, for now, fix it with simple `NSFetchRequest`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really helpful. Not only solving my problem, but I'm also glad to hear about the other tips you gave me about my programming, since I am still a beginner.